# Grouping by rows in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I would like a way to perform grouping and aggregate functions when my source data isn't already grouped nicely.  For example, given the following dataframe:

```
#Create a DataFrame
d = {
    'Name':['Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine','Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine',
            'Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine','Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine'],
'Exam':['Semester 1','Semester 1','Semester 1','Semester 1','Semester 1','Semester 1',
        'Semester 2','Semester 2','Semester 2','Semester 2','Semester 2','Semester 2'],

'Subject':['Mathematics','Mathematics','Mathematics','Science','Science','Science',
           'Mathematics','Mathematics','Mathematics','Science','Science','Science'],
'Score':[62,47,55,74,31,77,85,63,42,67,89,81]}
```

I would like to be able to print a table that aggregates the results by score ranges - for example:

```
Score        Subject        Qty
60-70        Mathematics    2
             Science        1
70-80        Mathematics    1
             Science        2
```

So far I haven't been able to figure this out... Any brilliant ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(df.groupby([pd.cut(df['Score'],bins=[60,70,80]),
             'Subject'])
   .size()
   .to_frame('Qty')
)
```

Output:

```
                      Qty
Score    Subject         
(60, 70] Mathematics    2
         Science        1
(70, 80] Mathematics    0
         Science        2
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will give it a shot - the actual dataset looks a little different so I will see what I can do.